# Error Posting Message with status code 302 to google app script from Loriot

Tags: http, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets, lora

I'm trying to set up a LoRa communication network.

I have a gateway module RHF0M301-915, PRI 2 Bridge RHF4T002 with raspberry pi 3 B (as Lora gateway); a seeeduino board with GPS, RHF76-052AM.

Both registered in the Loriot Server.

I managed to send GPS data from seeeduino board to the Loriot server's dashboard via ABP method. I want to output the data to my android mobile application to show users where are the end node located on the map.

I choose to use HTTP Push (one of the output option provided by the Loriot server).

I followed these [guidelines](https://blog.squix.org/2017/11/using-seeeduino-lorawan-with-gps-and-loriot-io.html).

I able to send GPS data to the Loriot Server but the HTTP push cannot push the data to the google sheets created as in the guidelines. I get the following error messages in the log of the Loriot server:

> Error POSTing message | "err":"POSTing message to
>   \"https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyUaIl4t8PZxoXswCW2kc0I-ZfUl5DVucsD0CwtW3Rn4YAP2qpo/exec\"
>   failed with 302 status
>   code","appid":3195667320,"url":"https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyUaIl4t8PZxoXswCW2kc0I-ZfUl5DVucsD0CwtW3Rn4YAP2qpo/exec","seqno":132,"deveui":"4786C58B003C002A","data":{"statusCode":302},"message":"POSTing
>   message to
>   \"https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyUaIl4t8PZxoXswCW2kc0I-ZfUl5DVucsD0CwtW3Rn4YAP2qpo/exec\"
>   failed with 302 status
>   code","targetUrl":"https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyUaIl4t8PZxoXswCW2kc0I-ZfUl5DVucsD0CwtW3Rn4YAP2qpo/exec","statusCode":302,"reqBody":null,"errName":"Error","instance":"nwk-1"

The following code sent the data to google sheet:

```html
// 2017 by Daniel Eichhorn, https://blog.squix.org
// Inspired by https://gist.github.com/bmcbride/7069aebd643944c9ee8b
// Create or open an existing Sheet and click Tools > Script editor and enter the code below
// 1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
// 2. Publish > Deploy as web app
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version'
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
// 3. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  Logger.log("arrived in handleResponse");
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME); 

    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = [];
    var headerRow = [];

    row.push(jsonData.rssi);
    row.push(jsonData.seqno);
    row.push(jsonData.data);
    var humidityHex = jsonData.data.substring(0, 2);
    row.push(parseInt(humidityHex, 16));
    var tempHex = jsonData.data.substring(2, 4);
    row.push(parseInt(tempHex, 16) - 100);
    var latHex = jsonData.data.substring(4, 10);
    var lonHex = jsonData.data.substring(10, 16);
    var latEncoded = parseInt(latHex, 16);
    var lonEncoded = parseInt(lonHex, 16);
    row.push((latEncoded / 8388606) * 90);
    row.push((lonEncoded / 8388606) * 180);

    row.push(jsonData.freq);
    row.push(jsonData.ack);
    row.push(jsonData.fcnt);
    row.push(jsonData.dr);
    row.push(jsonData.bat);
    row.push(jsonData.port);
    row.push(jsonData.snr);
    row.push(jsonData.EUI);
    row.push(jsonData.cmd);
    row.push(jsonData.ts);

    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e) {
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } 
}
```

This is the code to command the seeeduino board to send gps data to the Loriot server.

```html
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <LoRaWan.h>
#include "DHT.h"


TinyGPSPlus gps;
#define DHTPIN A0 // what pin we're connected to

#define DHTTYPE DHT11 // DHT 11
 
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
char buffer[256];


void setup(void)
{
    SerialUSB.begin(115200);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    
    lora.init();
    
    memset(buffer, 0, 256);
    lora.getVersion(buffer, 256, 1);
    SerialUSB.print(buffer); 
    
    memset(buffer, 0, 256);
    lora.getId(buffer, 256, 1);
    SerialUSB.print(buffer);
    SerialUSB.println("That was the id");
    // void setId(char *DevAddr, char *DevEUI, char *AppEUI);
    lora.setId("00C4E57D", "4786C58B003C002A", "526973696E674846");
    // setKey(char *NwkSKey, char *AppSKey, char *AppKey);
    lora.setKey("2B7E151628AED2A6ABF7158809CF4F3C", "2B7E151628AED2A6ABF7158809CF4F3C", "8413360695ABE271EB2A515386F0093E ");
    
    lora.setDeciveMode(LWOTAA);
    lora.setDataRate(DR2, AS923);
    
    lora.setChannel(0, 923.0);
    lora.setChannel(1, 923.2);
    lora.setChannel(2, 923.4);
    lora.setChannel(3, 923.6);
    lora.setChannel(4, 923.8);
    lora.setChannel(5, 924.0);
    lora.setChannel(6, 924.2);
    lora.setChannel(7, 924.4);
    
    lora.setReceiceWindowFirst(2, 923.0);
    lora.setReceiceWindowSecond(923.2, DR2);
    lora.setAdaptiveDataRate(false);
    
    lora.setPower(10);
    
    while(!lora.setOTAAJoin(JOIN, 20000));
    SerialUSB.println("After OTAA join");

    // Start DHT sensor
    dht.begin();
}

void loop(void)
{   
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      gps.encode(Serial.read());
    }
    if (gps.altitude.isUpdated()) {
      SerialUSB.println(gps.altitude.meters());
      SerialUSB.print("LAT=");  SerialUSB.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);
      SerialUSB.print("LONG="); SerialUSB.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
      SerialUSB.print("ALT=");  SerialUSB.println(gps.altitude.meters());
      long latEncoded = (gps.location.lat() * 8388606) / 90;
      long lonEncoded = (gps.location.lng() * 8388606) / 180;
      SerialUSB.print("Lat encoded: "); 
      SerialUSB.println(latEncoded);
      SerialUSB.print("Lon encoded: "); 
      SerialUSB.println(lonEncoded);
      float h = dht.readHumidity();
      float t = dht.readTemperature();
      SerialUSB.print("Humidity is: ");
      SerialUSB.print(h);
      SerialUSB.print(", Temperature: ");
      SerialUSB.print(t);
      bool result = false;
      byte data[10] = {0};
      data[0] = h;
      data[1] = t + 100;
      data[2] = (byte) (latEncoded >> 16);
      data[3] = (byte) (latEncoded >> 8);
      data[4] = (byte) latEncoded;
      
      data[5] = (byte) (lonEncoded >> 16);
      data[6] = (byte) (lonEncoded >> 8);
      data[7] = (byte) lonEncoded;

      result = lora.transferPacket(data, 10);
      //result = lora.transferPacket(data, 10, 10);
      
      if(result)
      {
          short length;
          short rssi;
          
          memset(buffer, 0, 256);
          length = lora.receivePacket(buffer, 256, &rssi);
          
          if(length)
          {
              SerialUSB.print("Length is: ");
              SerialUSB.println(length);
              SerialUSB.print("RSSI is: ");
              SerialUSB.println(rssi);
              SerialUSB.print("Data is: ");
              for(unsigned char i = 0; i < length; i ++)
              {
                  SerialUSB.print("0x");
                  SerialUSB.print(buffer[i], HEX);
                  SerialUSB.print(" ");
              }
              SerialUSB.println();
          }
          delay(1000 * 60 * 5);
      }
    }
    
}
```

How can I handle the status code 302, I know that it has to do with redirect the target URL that I used to some temporary URL. But I have no idea how to handle it.

Comment: Is the error in Apps Script? Or in your application code? If in your application code, why haven't you included that here?

Comment: The error is on the Loriot server's log. I'm using arduino ide to command the seeeduino board to send gps data to the Loriot server. The data is displayed on the Loriot server. But the data is not write in the google sheet with the error shown above. I have put the code in my question above. Thanks